# How do you pass values to another script under a foreach statement?

Tags: powershell, jobs

I want to run 1 script multiple times for each port select via a range and pass through the port details in which it needs to use to connect, I was trying to use the following:

```
$availableports = 7000..7050
while ($availableports -notcontains $SPort) {
    [string]$SPort= Read-Host -Prompt 'S Ports'
}
while ($availableports -notcontains $FPort) {
    [string]$FPort= Read-Host -Prompt 'F Ports'
}

$massport = ($SPort)..($FPort)

foreach ($Port in $massport) {
    C:\PShell-Projects\Firmware\SCP-FMUPv2.ps1 -Port "$Port"
}
```

This works but will not move on to the next port until the referenced script has finished.

I would like to run them all in parallel.

I tried

```
$arg = @("-Port", $portm)
Start-Job -FilePath C:\PShell-Projects\Firmware\SCP-FMUPv2.ps1 -ArgumentList $arg
```

but the job becomes blocked and when I used `Receive-Job` it asks for the port to open a connection to, which should have been sent as part of the loop.

I seem to be missing some key information, but don't know where to start and well when looking up the information nothing seems to be standing out.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
$jobs = @()
foreach ($Port in $massport) {
    $jobs += start-job -FilePath "job.ps1" -ArgumentList @($port)
}

Receive-Job $jobs -Wait
```

(no named arguments in ArgumentList).

You can also take a look at [Invoke-Parallel](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Run-Parallel-Parallel-377fd430) function, which simplifies running parallel tasks.

Comment: Thanks for help, i tired running this and found that it would indeed open all sessions at once but would then request the port details individually, which shows it wouldn't pass through the $Port values in the foreach statement.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use -asjob after your `C:\PShell-Projects\Firmware\SCP-FMUPv2.ps1 -Port "$Port` command to have it just do them all simultaneously.

If the ps1 won't take -asjob, you might be able to wrap it with `invoke-command {}`

Comment: Thanks for your help, I am trying  "Invoke-Command -FilePath C:\PShell-Projects\Firmware\SCP-FMUPv2.ps1 -Port $port -AsJob" but fails as "[localhost] Connecting to remote server localhost failed. this might be the way, im looking into that error.

Comment: If your doing it locally invoke-command is more or less useless redundancy.   You need to do invoke-command -computername $computers {command -asjob}.  But if you're doing it locally I meant invoke-command {command} -asjob